# How to I go to next activity after login with Google?

Tags: android

After success login with Google, I would like go to next activity, how can I do that? This all my code, I used Firebase in order to login

```html
package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Icon;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.telecom.GatewayInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import static com.example.asus.myapplication.R.id.sign_google;


public class sign_in_screen extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,View.OnClickListener {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    SignInButton  signInButton;
    Button but_sing_out;
private TextView textview;
    private ImageView ImgAvatar;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN =9001;
    private static final String TAG ="signInActivity";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener muAuthstateListener;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in_screen);



        Toolbar my_toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.tb_title0);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso=new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this,this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
                .build();

        textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        ImgAvatar=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imag_avatar);
        signInButton=(SignInButton)findViewById(sign_google);
        but_sing_out=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but_sing_out);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        but_sing_out.setOnClickListener(this);



    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.sign_google:
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.but_sing_out:
                singout();
                break;

        }

    }



    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent=Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestcode,resultcode,data);
        if (requestcode==RC_SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result=Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);


        }

    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG,"handleSignInResult:"+ result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount acc=result.getSignInAccount();
            textview.setText("Welcome"+ acc.getDisplayName()+"\n"+"\n"+":email"+ acc.getEmail());
            try {
                String PohtoUlr=acc.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                Picasso.with(sign_in_screen.this).load(PohtoUlr).into(ImgAvatar);
               
            } catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onConnectionFailed:"+connectionResult);


    }

    private void singout() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(sign_in_screen.this,"LOG OUT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: call new activity from handlesignin result method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use intent to move to next page
and you should include it after the catch statement.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Nextpage.class);

startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

Go for Intent and for more info refer

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TheActivityYouWantToGoTo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your new Intent from handleSignInResult() method like this.

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG,"handleSignInResult:"+ result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount acc=result.getSignInAccount();
            textview.setText("Welcome"+ acc.getDisplayName()+"\n"+"\n"+":email"+ acc.getEmail());
            try {
                String PohtoUlr=acc.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                Picasso.with(sign_in_screen.this).load(PohtoUlr).into(ImgAvatar);

            } catch (Exception e){

            }
            startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class));
        }
    }
```